# How would a king have phrased "I need to use the bathroom"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, british-english

With literary or historical references, what phrase would an English-speaking monarch have used to indicate to either their attendants or to their court that they were in need of using the toilet facilities?

Comment: ha I'm not sure that would be necessary, a simple "get out" would suffice, and no-one would risk the beheading to question him

Comment: A little facetiously, but truthfully, I think the answer is: being monarch, however they want. The English monarchy goes way back into the mists of time until at least 1707 and arguably to the present day. In those times they spoke a Celtic language, Norse, Old, Middle, and Modern English, German, French, Dutch, and probably other languages. However, I find it very unlikely they would have used the euphemisms common in the aspiring court or, later, middle classes. For one thing, they need never explain their actions. One probably once said "I will retire for a moment", if you want some answer!

Comment: Where even kings must go on foot: http://history250.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/where-even-kings-must-go-on-foot/

Comment: Maybe English kings must go there on foot, but I'd be amazed if there wasn't a drive-through somewhere in the US?

Comment: Seriously, who downvoted this? It's a real question, with real answers. Uptight much?

Comment: @DanGayle: No, as phrased it's a joke; by newspaper announcement? If you don't put much effort into your wording, you can expect downvotes, no matter what the subject.

Comment: According to Mel Brooks it's, "Oh Piss Boy...."

Comment: I'm to the throne room.

Comment: @TimLymington How else to phrase it? There's no way to say it more straightforward than I did.

Comment: The monarch merely requests that the Groom of the Stool attend to the matters of his office.

Comment: 'I'm going out for a royal shake.'

Comment: Edited to break out of the hold

Answer (score 1):

It substantially depends on which kings and in which century you are interested.

On a visit I made to a Tudor house earlier this year, where they were trying to recreate an authentic 16th-century atmosphere, the staff, dressed in period costume and speaking the language of the Tudors, referred to the toilets formally as 'The house of easement', and informally as 'the jakes'.

Fortunately for the benefit of visitors and to comply with Health & Safety law they had installed modern plumbing!